# iOS Popover and tableviewcontroller refreshing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm writing a project that simulates a Master/detail layout for iPad.
So i've a masterView(UITableView), a detailView(UICollectionView), a global Navigation Bar and a TabBar.
The tabbar is filled with some catecories i need to choose from and the masterview is filled according to the tabbaritem selected.

In landscape mode, when both master and detail view are shown, everything works fine.
In portrait mode, my master view is hidden and i've got a button that open a popupcontroller with my master in it. The problem is that this popup doesn't seems to show the changes made on the masterview content

the MasterView is a UITableViewController.
I've correctly implemented the delegate and datasource method.

Here is the code to open/dismiss the popover

```
if(myPopIsVisible)
{
    myPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:myMasterView];
    [myPop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    myPopIsVisible = YES;
}
else
{
    [myPop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    myPopIsVisible = NO;
}
```

Checking in debug it lend me to the correct content of myMasterView (number and content of rows) but it only show the first one loaded by the app.

I'm using ARC...

This is myMasterView class implementation

```
@implementation myMasterView{
    NSArray *cellTitles;
    NSArray *cellIco;
    NSArray *cellTag;
}

- (void) setData:(NSArray *)titles :(NSArray *)icos :(NSArray *)tags
{
     cellTitles = titles;
     cellIco = icos;
     cellTag = tags;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = [cellTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.tag = [[cellTag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
    #warning icona non impostata
    //    cell.imageView.image = [cellIco objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [cellTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(isPopover)
    {
        isPopover = NO;
        [master dismissPopoverController];
    }

}
```